# What's the difference?

Tags: objective-c

I'll preface my question by saying that I'm a beginner objective-c developer. What is the difference between:

NSString * foo;

NSString* foo;

NSString *foo;

Is there a difference?

Comment: May I suggest choosing a more detailed title text time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All three simply declare a variable named foo of type NSString *. It is really just a matter of style preference.

Some people prefer to put the asterisk next to the type to emphasize that this is a pointer type.

Some people prefer to put the asterisk next to the variable to emphasize the requirements of the language. Every pointer variable in a multiple declaration needs to have the asterisk, as in:

```
NSString *foo, *bar;
```

My personal preference is actually the first of your examples with a space before and after the asterisk, reserving the use of an asterisk directly before the variable for use in dereferencing the pointer. I also avoid declaring more than one variable in a single declaration.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, they mean all three the same thing. Only it is considered to be better to declare it like:

```
NSString *foo;
```

Because when you add a second variable your intention is more clear:

```
NSString *foo,*bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

No difference. The three work the same.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you have the space in a different location in each example :-)

Semantically, there is no difference whatsoever.  Stylistically, the last form is preferred.